# From where can I get any example web applications developed in Java EE in order to learn from them?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am looking forward to learning web application development in Java(EE) and thus I am looking for any sample web projects from where I can learn about that.

Please let me know of any resources available..

thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some tutorials on many different frameworks used in Java J2EE development.  I recommend Spring, but there are plenty of other examples here as well:

http://www.mkyong.com/

Comment: I was thinking of working without frameworks initially & getting a complete Java feel. Would you recommend beginning with the frameworks instead? Can you point out any links that contains without framework  projects ?

Comment: @Raj - Good idea actually.  Best to learn the fundamentals so you understand what the frameworks encapsulate:  http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Java Blueprints is very good: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/blueprints-141945.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.holisticon.de/cms/EJB3Buch/SourceCode

Thats a ejb3 example (working ticket service) from a very good german book called "ejb 3 professional" which has sadly not been translated yet. You may encounter german comments, havent checked yet.

Comment: @Raj - Did you enter the Anonymous username and password?

Comment: User and passwd is listed on that page: Subversion Repository Access (read-only) User: anonymous
Password: anon